# Installing libmysqlclient18 on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, mysql

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04.

I'm trying to install mapr-metrics, which keeps failing because it requests libmysqlclient18 or 16, whereas apt-get install libmysqlclient yields libmysqlclient20.

Is there some way I can install libmysqlclient18 on my ubuntu machine?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

download the package here, and install it..

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/xenial/amd64/libmysqlclient18/5.6.25-0ubuntu1

it should work.

Comment: FYI, FWIW, some later versions (`5.6.28-1ubuntu3` at time of writing) are listed at: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/xenial/amd64/libmysqlclient18